# Help remembering a Putnam Problem

Tags: functional-equations, contest-math

I recall that there was a Putnam problem which went something like this:

Find all real functions satisfying

$$f(s^2+f(t)) = t+f(s)^2$$

for all $s,t \in \mathbb{R}$.

There was a cool trick to solving it that I wanted to remember. But I don't know which test it was from and google isn't much help for searching with equations.

Does anyone know which problem I am thinking of so I can look up that trick?

Comment: Are you saying this is the question and you're looking for the trick, or is it more like you're looking for the question's correct statement?

Comment: I was looking for both the question's correct statement, as well as the trick. I have encountered a similar problem which I wanted to try and apply the same trick to. It turns out my problem was much easier because I am allowed to assume differentiability, but I am still interested in this problem just for fun.

Comment: Well I guess you got what you wanted. I actually found an answer too while playing with it but since there are plenty of solutions in the answers below I didn't bother. Thanks for posting it, it was fun =)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was problem 2 in the International Mathematical Olympiad in 1992 (Russia).

You may read several solutions [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?p=366399&sid=37c34ff252eb0a7b654c5a0bbc2ae61d#p366399).

Answer (score 2):

1971 A2 was "Determine all polynomials $P(x)$ such that $P(x^2+1)=(P(x))^2+1$ and $P(0)=0$."

Answer (score 2):

No idea. But I have a book called *Putnam and Beyond* by Gelca and Andreescu, and on page 185 they present a problem from  a book called *Functional Equations: A Problem Solving Approach* by B. J. Venkatachala, from Prism Books PVT Ltd., 2002. I think the Ltd. means the publisher is British.

Almost, the publisher is (or was?) in India (Bangalore):

http://www.prismbooks.com/

http://www.hindbook.com/order_info.php

EDIT, December 3, 2011: The book is available, at least, from an online firm in India that is similar to Amazon.com

http://www.flipkart.com/m/books/8172862652

on

http://www.flipkart.com/

I cannot tell whether they ship outside India. But it does suggest that contacting the publisher by email is likely to work.